# Foreach in wpf (cannot convert char to string)?

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, foreach

Each time I add an item in the list **ListData** that I have created I have to check that does not exist.

This is the element:

```
public ObservableCollection<LabelGroup_RowItem> ListData = new
ObservableCollection<LabelGroup_RowItem>();

public class LabelGroup_RowItem
{
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
}

element.Name = TextEdit_GroupName.Text;  
foreach (string x in ucLabel.ListData[0].Name)
{
      if (x.Equals(element.Name))
      {
           MessageBox.Show("....");
      }
}
```

How should I do?

Comment: Iterating through a `string` returns a sequence of `chars`. What do you actually try to do with your foreach-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Linq - this will match if any item in ListData(.Name) matches your text field

```
string TextToMatch = TextEdit_GroupName.Text;

if(ListData.Any(x => x.Name == TextToMatch))
{
MessageBox.Show(string.format("{0} already exists",TextToMatch);
}
```

bare in mind this is mostly psuedo, but it should work

Comment: It won't work because `x` isn't defined within the `MessageBox`es scope

Comment: @Sayse as stated "mostly psuedo" but i've fixed it

Answer (score 2):

While it's hard to know what `ucLabel` is, you probably meant:

```
foreach (var x in ucLabel.ListData)
{
      if (x.Name.Equals(element.Name))
      {
           MessageBox.Show("....");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[about equals metchod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If Name property is unique try to compare it with simple '==' operator.
Also your foreach loop looks wierd. I am not sure if this: ucLabel.ListData[0].Name
 is IEnumerable. Maybe you think about

```
foreach (var x in ucLabel.ListData){
     if (x.Name==element.Name) { do something }
}
```

Also remember to avoid adding or removing ListData content in foreach loop becous it will crash your code.

Comment: I do not know why but I do not work. 

When I add a new element with the same name as an existing one causes me the duplicate.